How to query with drizzle-kit if two users like each other
I want to query a user's mutual matches for all the events they have ever attended.
I’m using Drizzle-kit with SQLite, Turso, and Next.js. I have a query that returns the users they liked, but it doesn't return mutual matches.
I've tried everything, but it still isn't working. I think I need to add another innerJoin to join usersToEvents again.
I also tried using
const r1 = aliasedTable(...) and
const r2 = aliasedTable(...).
The const matches = ... part of the query doesn't seem to work correctly either.
export async function getUserEventsWithMatches(
  userId: string,
  locale: LocaleType
): Promise<EventWithMatches[]> {
  const attendedEvents = await db
    .select({
      eventId: events.id,
      title: eventTranslations.title,
      date: events.date,
      matchesRevealed: events.matchesRevealed,
      location: {
        id: locations.id,
        postalCode: locations.postalCode,
        city: locations.city,
        address: locations.address,
        houseNumber: locations.houseNumber,
        name: locations.name,
      },
    })
    .from(events)
    .innerJoin(usersToEvents, eq(events.id, usersToEvents.eventId))
    .leftJoin(locations, eq(locations.id, events.locationId))
    .leftJoin(
      eventTranslations,
      and(
        eq(eventTranslations.eventType, events.eventType),
        eq(eventTranslations.locale, locale)
      )
    )
    .where(eq(usersToEvents.userId, userId))
    .groupBy(events.id)
    .orderBy(desc(events.date))
    .all();

  const matches = await db
    .select({
      eventId: eventUserUserRatings.eventId,
      userId: users.id,
      nickname: users.nickname,
      instagram: users.instagram,
      facebook: users.facebook,
      email: users.email,
    })
    .from(eventUserUserRatings)
    .innerJoin(users, eq(eventUserUserRatings.ratedUserId, users.id))
    .where(
      and(
        eq(eventUserUserRatings.raterUserId, userId),
        eq(eventUserUserRatings.isLiked, true)
      )
    )
    .all();

  const eventMatchesMap: Record<string, MatchingUser[]> = matches.reduce(
    (acc: Record<string, MatchingUser[]>, match: MatchingUser) => {
      const { eventId, ...userMatch } = match;
      if (!acc[eventId]) {
        acc[eventId] = [];
      }
      acc[eventId].push({ eventId, ...userMatch });
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );

  const result: EventWithMatches[] = attendedEvents.map(
    (event: AttendedEvent) => ({
      ...event,
      matches: eventMatchesMap[event.eventId] || [],
    })
  );

  return result;
}

The relationship:
import { relations } from "drizzle-orm";
import {
  integer,
  primaryKey,
  sqliteTable,
  text,
} from "drizzle-orm/sqlite-core";

import { events } from "./events";
import { users } from "./users";

export const eventUserUserRatings = sqliteTable(
  "event_user_user_ratings",
  {
    eventId: text("event_id")
      .notNull()
      .references(() => events.id),
    raterUserId: text("rater_user_id")
      .notNull()
      .references(() => users.id),
    ratedUserId: text("rated_user_id")
      .notNull()
      .references(() => users.id),
    isLiked: integer("is_liked", { mode: "boolean" }).notNull(),
  },
  (t) => ({
    pk: primaryKey({ columns: [t.eventId, t.raterUserId, t.ratedUserId] }),
  })
);

export const eventUserUserRatingsRelations = relations(
  eventUserUserRatings,
  ({ one }) => ({
    event: one(events, {
      fields: [eventUserUserRatings.eventId],
      references: [events.id],
    }),
    raterUser: one(users, {
      fields: [eventUserUserRatings.raterUserId],
      references: [users.id],
    }),
    ratedUser: one(users, {
      fields: [eventUserUserRatings.ratedUserId],
      references: [users.id],
    }),
  })
);

